# media queries in LESS

Tags: css, less, media-queries

I am somewhat new to media queries and LESS and I am trying to figure out some best practices that might be shared in the industry and that might also have technical advantages. One thing I noticed with regards to LESS syntax is that you can wrap an element inside a media query and you can also wrap the media query inside the element. Both will have the desired result. Is one method to be preferred over the other and if so, why?

Example:

```
#wrap{
    @media(max-width: 991px){
        margin-top: 60px;
        margin-bottom: -350px;
        padding: 0 0 350px;
    }
}
```

vs.

```
@media(max-width: 991px){
    #wrap{
        margin-top: 60px;
        margin-bottom: -350px;
        padding: 0 0 350px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your LESS snippets do indeed produce the same CSS output. The [LESS documentation](http://www.lesscss.org/#-nested-rules) does specifically highlight the fact that you can nest media queries within a selector, so I would say that your first snippet would be considered better practice. The main argument for your first code block is that it keeps all the rules you want to apply to your `wrap` element all in one code block.